# pandas / matplotlib: change tick label format (force plain not scientific)

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have a `pandas dataframe` with 2 columns in the below format:

```
df.head()
                            column1  column2
time                                                                        
1900-01-01 12:30:05.089883  19042.5  19042.8615   
1900-01-01 12:30:05.210055  19042.5  19042.8615   
1900-01-01 12:30:05.290165  19042.5  19042.8615   
1900-01-01 12:30:05.449856  19042.5  19042.8615
```

I am plotting the columns on the same `matplotlib axes subplot`

```
def plot(df):
    ax = df.plot(y='column1', figsize=(20, 8))
    df.plot(y='column2', ax=ax)

    # this doesn't make a difference
    ax.ticklabel_format(style='plain', axis='y')    

    mpl.pyplot.show()

plot(df)
```

[image: pandas plot]

I'd like to print the y-axis in `plain` format - how can I force it to stop using `scientific`?

That is, the y-axis goes from `0` to `6`, and has an additional label `1.9037e4`. I would like it to fo from `19037` to `19043`

I've tried this, but it doesn't make a difference:

```
ax.ticklabel_format(style='plain', axis='y')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [docs](http://matplotlib.org/api/ticker_api.html#module-matplotlib.ticker):

> To reduce the chances that the ticklabels overlap the ticks are
>   labeled as deltas from a fixed offset. For example:
>
> `ax.plot(np.arange(2000, 2010), range(10))`
>
> will have tick of 0-9 with an offset of +2e3. If this is not desired
>   turn off the use of the offset on the default formatter:
>
> `ax.get_xaxis().get_major_formatter().set_useOffset(False)`
>
> set the rcParam `axes.formatter.useoffset=False` to turn it off
>   globally, or set a different formatter.

So, you can write

```
 ax.get_yaxis().get_major_formatter().set_useOffset(False)
```

to turn off the offset.

Comment: Thanks - that worked perfectly. For some reason I find it really hard to find what I'm looking for in the matplotlib documentation